# $fn.insertAfter() and $fn.after() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter, jquery-after

I understand that `$fn.insertAfter()` is used to insert element after the element supplied as the argument. How's `$fn.after()` different from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$.fn.after()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) inserts an element after the **target** element, on which you call it.

```
$('div').after('<div>new div</div>');
```

whereas, [`$.fn.insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) inserts the **target** element after the node you specify:

```
$('<div>new div</div>').insertAfter($('#someid'));
```

The latter is mostly prefered, because you keep a **reference** to the newly created element and can chain more methods on it. So for instance:

```
$('<div>new div</div>')
   .insertAfter($('#someid'))
   .attr('foo', 'bar')
   .css({
      'background-color': 'red'
   });
```

is possible. You cannot do that with [`.after()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/). The same thing is for [`.append()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/) / [`.appendTo()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and [`.insertBefore()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) / [`.before()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Comment: so basically the functions do the same things , except returning the reference to the newly created element.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the same thing, the difference is the context of the selector. `insertAfter` inserts the selected element after the parameter
`after` inserts the parameter after the selected element.

```
$('<div id="foo"></div>').insertAfter('#bar');
$('#bar').after('<div id="foo"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting straight from the documentation:

> **The `.after()` and `.insertAfter()`
>   methods perform the same task. The
>   major *difference is in the
>   syntax***—specifically, in the placement
>   of the content and target. With
>   `.after()`, the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container
>   after which the content is inserted.
>   With `.insertAfter()`, on the other
>   hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as
>   markup created on the fly, and it is
>   inserted after the target container.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://api.jquery.com/after/) mentions that they perform the same task but have different syntax.